# JQuery - Scroll functions are not working

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'd like to display circlefull animation on page scroll with jquery, but no one scroll function works.

```
> $("body").scrollTop();
  0

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'>    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function (){
      alert('ready');
$('#htmlbody').scroll( function (){
      alert('scroll'); 
});
});
</script>
```

No one works. What's problem in? Any errors are not logging in console also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#htmbody')` is wrong.

Use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        alert('scroll'); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/wqZ6G/

If you want to call `HTML` and `BODY` to animate scroll top use:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'400px'},{duration:1000});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/wqZ6G/1/

Comment: BTW, you should use .on method of jQuery, instead of .scroll or whatever other... Like this: $(window).on('scroll', function(){});

Comment: <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function (){
      alert('scroll-1'); 
});
</script>